# Program to track the passing of a ball in a circle of 10 people using boolean

Tags: c++

I am stuck on this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

You have ten people sitting in a ring as shown below. A ball is continuously passed around the ring in
sequence. Initially person 0 has the ball. A user inputs a number between 0 and 9 inclusive. The ball is
then passed down that number of people. For example, if the user enters a 2, the ball is passed from
person 0 to person 2. If the user then enters a 3, the ball is passed from person 2 to person 5. Be careful
that from person 9, the ball goes back to person 0, so if person 9 currently has the ball and a 2 is
entered, then the ball will be passed to person 1.

Write a program to simulate this passing ball game. You need to use ten variables (Person0 to Person9)
of type bool to represent the ten people. Assign the value true to the person variable that is holding the
ball. Otherwise assign the value false for the people that are not holding the ball. After each input the
program must actually assign the “ball” to the person that the ball is passed to by reassigning the
true/false values to the affected people. After each round, a message is also printed out saying who
ends up holding the ball. This continues until a negative number is entered.

I am having trouble with continuing around the circle after the last person gets the ball. Also not sure how to change boolean variable each time a new person gets the ball.

```
 int main(){
  bool t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9;
  int passes = 0, newLocation = 0;
  do{
  cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
  cin >> passes;
  newLocation += passes;
  cout << endl;
    if(newLocation == 0)
      cout << "\nPerson zero has the ball\n";
      t0 = true;
    if(newLocation == 1)
      cout << "\nPerson one has the ball\n";
      t1 = true;
    if(newLocation == 2)
      cout << "\nPerson two has the ball\n";
      t2 = true;
    if(newLocation == 3)
      cout << "\nPerson three has the ball\n";
      t3 = true;
    if(newLocation == 4)
      cout << "\nPerson four has the ball\n";
      t4 = true;
    if(newLocation == 5)
      cout << "\nPerson five has the ball\n";
      t5 = true;
    if(newLocation == 6)
      cout << "\nPerson six has the ball\n";
      t6 = true;
    if(newLocation == 7)
      cout << "\nPerson seven has the ball\n";
      t7 = true;
    if(newLocation == 8)
      cout << "\nPerson eight has the ball\n";
      t8 = true;
    if(newLocation == 9)
      cout << "\nPerson nine has the ball\n";
      t9 = true;
    if(passes < 0){
      cout << "Mom says dinner is ready!" << endl;
      t0 = true;
      break;
      }
    if(newLocation >= 10){
      newLocation = 0 + (newLocation % passes);
      cout << newLocation;
          if(newLocation == 0)
      cout << "\nPerson zero has the ball\n";
      t0 = true;
    if(newLocation == 1)
      cout << "\nPerson one has the ball\n";
      t1 = true;
    if(newLocation == 2)
      cout << "\nPerson two has the ball\n";
      t2 = true;
    if(newLocation == 3)
      cout << "\nPerson three has the ball\n";
      t3 = true;
    if(newLocation == 4)
      cout << "\nPerson four has the ball\n";
      t4 = true;
    if(newLocation == 5)
      cout << "\nPerson five has the ball\n";
      t5 = true;
    if(newLocation == 6)
      cout << "\nPerson six has the ball\n";
      t6 = true;
    if(newLocation == 7)
      cout << "\nPerson seven has the ball\n";
      t7 = true;
    if(newLocation == 8)
      cout << "\nPerson eight has the ball\n";
      t8 = true;
    if(newLocation == 9)
      cout << "\nPerson nine has the ball\n";
      t9 = true;
    if(passes < 0)
      cout << "Mom says dinner is ready!" << endl;
      t0 = true;
      break;
      }
    }
  }while(newLocation >= 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on? Best to give it a try as described and if you run into troubles once you've got some code written come ask something specific about that.

Comment: okay thank you. I will try to add my code, I was having trouble with the formatting on this website since this is my first attempt posting here. Thanks again.

Comment: Paste the code into the question then select it and use the `{}` button to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this before the edit, so refer to your original code to see the differences. I added comments to explain what I did.

One of the problems is the lack of `{}` around the code after the `if` statements. Without them only the first statement after the `if` is conditional.

```
if(newLocation == 0)
      cout << "\nPerson zero has the ball\n"; // Executes based on the condition
      t0 = true; // executes always
```

Some languages, like Python, use indenting to match things up but C++ does not, so you need braces. I recommend getting into the habit of always using them even when there is only a single line after the conditional. IMO it makes the code easier to read, shows explicit intent, and will never turn into a bug when you add another line that should be conditional but isn't because you didn't have the braces.

The other changes are pretty simple. I cleared all of the boolean variables to false before assigning the correct one to true and I used `%` (mod) to wrap the value around when it is increased past the end.

I don't use `using namespace std;` so I added the explicit `std::` prefix where needed. I recommend you get in that habit too. It may seem harmless and save you some typing, but someday you'll regret it, especially if you ever put it in a header.

I'm hoping that your next assignment teaches you how to do this using an array for the variables since it would be so much cleaner and simpler.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9;
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;

    // loop forever. The loop will exit when a negative number is entered.
    for(;;)
    {
        // Set all of the variables to false
        t0 = t1 = t2 = t3 = t4 = t5 = t6 = t7 = t8 = t9 = false;

        std::cout << "Enter a number:\n";
        std::cin >> num1;

        // negative number ends the game
        if (num1 < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Mom says dinner is ready!\n";
            break; // exit loop
        }

        // advance the ball
        // add the new value and use % to wrap it around
        num2 += num1;
        num2 %= 10;

        if (num2 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson zero has the ball\n";
            t0 = true;
        }
        if (num2 == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson one has the ball\n";
            t1 = true;
        }
        if (num2 == 2)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson two has the ball\n";
            t2 = true;
        }
        if (num2 == 3)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson three has the ball\n";
            t3 = true;
        }
        if (num2 == 4)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson four has the ball\n";
            t4 = true;
        }
        if (num2 == 5)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson five has the ball\n";
            t5 = true;
        }
        if (num2 == 6)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson six has the ball\n";
            t6 = true;
        }
        if (num2 == 7)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson seven has the ball\n";
            t7 = true;
        }
        if (num2 == 8)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson eight has the ball\n";
            t8 = true;
        }
        if (num2 == 9)
        {
            std::cout << "\nPerson nine has the ball\n";
            t9 = true;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's also possible to replace the `if` statements with a `switch` if you wanted to. For something like this it doesn't really matter, but there are cases where it might be preferred. That would look like this:

```
switch (num2)
{
case 0:
    std::cout << "\nPerson zero has the ball\n";
    t0 = true;
    break;
case 1:
    std::cout << "\nPerson zero has the ball\n";
    t0 = true;
    break;
}
...
```

Comment: Okay wow using num2 %= 10 helped a lot! Also I'll try to get in the habit of using std:: format instead of using namespace std; I didn't that could come back to bite me, great tips I appreciate it!